# Why can't I prevent page break?

Tags: page-breaking

I am newbie to Latex and I am just making some lists of some common commands and learning the syntax.

This is what I have at the end of my first page.

```
using left and right bracketing commands\\
$$3\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)$$
$$3\left[\frac{2}{5}\right]$$
$$3\left\{\frac{2}{5}\right\}$$
```

This produces three lines. On the first line is my comment. On the second and third line are the examples with parentheses and square brackets. But then the third example is output to the second page.

I have found the `\nopagebreak` and tried applying that. But I can't make it work.

```
using left and right bracketing commands\\
$$3\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)$$
$$3\left[\frac{2}{5}\right]$$
\nopagebreak $$3\left\{\frac{2}{5}\right\}$$
```

The last part still jumps to the second page. I'm not sure... should the `\nopagebreak` command sit on the same line in the code like that?

I tried placing it at the end, in front, and at the beginning of this paragraph (in the code). I also tried setting the argument to 4 to insist on preventing page break. Like `\nopagebreak[4]`. But that didn't help.

So how do I prevent page break at this point?

There is page number indicator (index) that sits in the foot of the page. This sits very high up on the page. So there is actually some real estate here, where the last example could sit, if Latex could only make the foot note margin smaller on all or for the current page, just somehow move the number in the foot note down a little.

So I'm curious why this is not working out for me. I can post a screenshot if that helps.

**Edit 1:** Here's a screenshot.

[image: page break]

You can see how high up that number one is. There is more than enough space there to place both the fraction example and the page index.

**Edit 2:** Here is the whole working example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
bracketing symbols;

parenthesis;
$$(x+1)$$

square brackets;
$$3[2+(x+1)]$$

curly brackets;\\
these are reserved symbols for coding in Latex\\
they are therefore normally not displayed
$${a,b,c}$$
so to display curly brackets in math mode\\
there needs to be a back slash in front\\
of each bracket
$$\{a,b,c\}$$

dollar sign;\\
the same is true for dollar sign\\
dollar signs are reserved to indicate\\
math mode in Latex\\
so to display a dollar sign in math mode\\
there needs to be a back slash in front of it

$$\$12.55$$

adjusting bracketing symbols to the height\\
of tall objects like fractions;

typing in only the bracket signs\\
$$3(\frac{2}{5})$$
$$3[\frac{2}{5}]$$
$$3\{\frac{2}{5}\}$$%curly brackets require an additional back slash

using left and right bracketing commands\\
$$3\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)$$
$$3\left[\frac{2}{5}\right]$$
\nopagebreak $$3\left\{\frac{2}{5}\right\}$$

\end{document}
```

As you can see here I do have a document class and a begin and end command. In case you thought I forgot those.

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn't use "$$": http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Also, your question is answered by the UK TeX FAQ: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=nopagebrk. `\nopagebreak` is a polite request. TeX is free to do as it damn well pleases if its algorithm determines that preventing a page break there would lead to too high "badness"

Comment: You should not use `\\ ` before displayed math, it sounds like your page layout is wrong, have you specified `a4paper` if you are using A4 (the default layout is US letter paper) or you could increase `\textheight` in the preamble or better use the `geometry` package. It is _always_ worth posting a _complete_ (small) document that shows the problem.

Comment: @kahen I don't understand any of that. Maybe I shouldn't use it, but I'm gonna do it anyway. It works and does what I want. Every single beginners guide to Latex is using single or double dollar sign to indicate math. So how can I ignore that and start using square brackets and things like that while following the tutorial? I need more knowledge to start making my own decisions about what commands/syntax/whatever to use and how to use it. I'm sure I will learn that when it comes to that one day. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why is `\\ ` not allowed? The format is A4, I remember choosing that option when I installed MikTex. Should I change that to Letter?

Comment: Once again, should `nopagebreak` sit on the same line like this `\nopagebreak $$3\left\{\frac{2}{5}\right\}$$`?

Comment: @Sammy --- what `LaTeX` beginners' guides recommend the use of double dollar signs?

Comment: the installation choice will affect printer drivers etc but latex documents are _portable_ between sites and don't use hidden defaults. the page layout will be us letter in the standard classes unless you use `[a4paper]`. You should generally avoid explicit spacing because the document class defines the spacing between the logical units of a document and putting explicit  spaces defeats that, but especially `\\ ` is almost always a mistake and a blank line should be used instead.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle By sites you mean using Latex on different websites? By explicit spacing you mean like marking explicitly where a new line begins (soft break) and where a new paragraph begins, etc? Does that mean I should just type all my text on a single line and let the interpreter/compiler do the line breaks automatically when it reaches the end of the paper? But what about paragraphs? Does have to be explicit, right?

Comment: no by "site" I meant different place, in particular once you posted your full document I could run it and know exactly where it made the page break without knowing what paper size you have in your printer. Paragraphs are a logical part of the document and should be marked up (with a blank line _not_ with `\\ `). TeX doesn't care whether you use newlines or spaces in your source they are generally all treated as spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you are printing a document formatted for US letter paper on an A4 page. If you use

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
```

Then it all fits on one page.

Comment: Thanks! This makes the whole "nopagebreak" thing excessive.

Answer (score 6):

For this particular case, increasing the page size (as suggested by David Carlisle) eliminates the problem. In general, to avoid page breaks in unfortunate places, it's important to tell `TeX` exactly what you want. In your case, you can take advantage of the fact that certain environments from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), including `gathered`, are placed in an unbreakable box which cannot split over two pages.  In the following example, your expressions appear on the first page, but if you increase the height of the rule by even one point, all three move onto a new page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\rule{1pt}{461pt} \par %Try changing to 462pt   
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
3\left(\frac{2}{5}\right) \\
3\left[\frac{2}{5}\right]\\
3\left\{\frac{2}{5}\right\}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

As a general rule, if you want to typeset any mathematics whose structure is more complicated than a single equation, you should use `amsmath`. This package is part of any standard `TeX` distribution. Note that you can abbreviate `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` to `\[` and `\]`, respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure I got the "why" of it. Is it because I use dollar signs to indicate math mode? How would I know if I have the amsmath package? I often hear comments use this and that package, but how do I tell what packages I've got? I don't know, two fifths... I don't see that as too complicated math.

Comment: I meant complicated from the typesetting point of view. Three equations that must not span a page break is a simple example, but as you try to do more with `LaTeX` you will probably encounter more elaborate cases. All standard distributions include `amsmath`.

Comment: Okay. Your "box" starts at `\begin{equation*}` and ends at `\end{equation*}` am I right? So that `\usepackage{amsmath}` is part of what is known as the preamble? I don't have to use any kind of start and end commands that uses amsmath for each line, I mean like "use amsmath here" and "stop amsmath here". That's what the `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` are doing and they link/call the `amsmath` package? Is that how it works?

Comment: @Sammy --- I have edited my answer. `\usepackage{amsmath}` is part of the preamble. With this included, `amsmath` environments such as `align`, `gather`, `multline`, etc. are available anywhere in your document. The `equation*` environment is redefined by `amsmath`, so `\begin{equation*}` does indeed invoke `amsmath` code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that using `\nopagebreak` is very tricky. And also that environment `\begin{samepage} \end{samepage}` works well for me.